# Alternativas ao método get

Tags: php, ajax, boleto

Estou fazendo um sistema e tem uma parte que vai mexer com boleto bancário. Por segurança/privacidade um usuário não pode ver o boleto do outro. Faço uma verificação toda vez que ele acessa essa página para ver se ele tem relação com aquele 'ID' de boleto.

Pensando nisso eu ia fazer por GET mas ia ficar ruim pois podia alterar o ID e acessar os outros. Aí eu fiz por AJAX mas não está funcionando. **Eu quero passar o ID, carregar a página e mostrar o boleto**. To usando o BOLETOPHP, um projeto já pronto.

Minha Requisicao AJAX

```js
$(document).on('click', '#getBoleto', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var uid = $(this).data('id');
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'gerarBoleto.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      id: uid
    },
    dataType: 'html'
  }).done(function() {
    window.open(href, '_blank');
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
$sqlQuery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tipe, banco, dv_agencia, agencia, dv_conta, conta, carteira, numeroBoleto FROM tbl_contaBanco WHERE id_Boleto = ?");
$sqlQuery->bindValue(1, $id);
$sqlQuery->execute();
$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Ai eu faço os outros cálculos etc... e quero mostra o boleto
```

ero mostra o boleto

Como eu mostro o boleto no final de carregar?? Onde deve está com erro?

Comment: Seu ajax retorna uma URL apontando para o diretório em que está o boleto ou como ele retorna esse boleto?

Comment: Quando o usuário faz autenticação, eu armazenaria esta informação por exemplo em uma sessão e resgataria a mesma no PHP. Não deixaria ela ser proveniente do frontend, pois forjar uma conexão desta passando outro ID é simples.

Comment: Usar AJAX não fará ser mais seguro, ainda poderá "acessar os outros", simplesmente usando `curl -X POST -d "id=1000" https://seusite.com/gerarBoleto.php`, pronto você irá obter o que estiver com `id` igual a `1000`. Inclusive podem simplesmente ver o código o código fonte (e/ou tráfego de rede) e replicar alterando o valor do POST.

Answer (score 0):

O que você esta fazendo não funciona, simplesmente pq o protocolo http é stateless. O processamento da geraboleto, será feito em um momento diferente do windows.open(), os dois vão abrir em momentos diferentes, sem que você tenha acesso ao ID.

O que você pode fazer é simplesmente fazer um post pra sua gera boleto, como um submite de form. já vai resolver.

```
<form method="POST" action="gerarBoleto.php">
     <input type="submit" name="botao" id="botao" value="BOTAO">    
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9991">
</form>
```

Usando este codigo no lugar onde vc gerao o boleto, você ne precisa do ajax.
No PHP você simplesmente pega o 'id' com:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```